# Php, html form submisson

Tags: php, html

Why does my code below always return "please fill out all fields"?

```
<?php
if($_POST['submitted']=='') {
    echo '
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Total Trip Time: <input type="text" name="EndTime"><br>
            Miles Per Hour:  <input type="text" name="Distance"><br>
                             <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    ';
} else if ($_POST['EndTime'] == '') {
    echo '
        <H1>Please fill out all fields</H1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Total Trip Time: <input type="text" name="EndTime"><br>
            Miles Per Hour:  <input type="text" name="Distance"><br>
                             <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    ';
} else if ($_POST['Distance'] == '') {
    echo '
        <H1 style="color: red;">Please fill out all fields</H1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Total Trip Time: <input type="text" name="EndTime"><br>
            Miles Per Hour:  <input type="text" name="Distance"><br>
                             <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    ';

} else {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    for ($StartTime = 1; $StartTime <= $_POST['EndTime']; $StartTime++) {
        echo"<tr><td>".$StartTime."</td><td>".$StartTime*$_POST['Distance']."</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why don't you just try adding `required` to the input field to make sure it's filled out? Not the answer you're looking for but that is just added check

Comment: Do you know which of the conditions triggers the message? Is the message red?

Comment: What result you want ? why you put all $_POST with empty value?

Comment: Why don't you use a composite `if` statement? `if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && $_POST['Distance'] != '' && ...)`

Comment: You don't check any condition inside if. You are constantly displaying please fill out all fields.

Comment: You need to figure out which `if` statement is triggering the error, give them some sort of unique identifier and work from there.

Comment: @user3010773 Because of the requirements the project.

Comment: @Floris could you please go over that in a bit more detail for me.

Comment: @Ruthless - see my detailed answer.

Comment: But why your if else condition is all empty. Can you post your html code here as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simplification of your form worked (for me - see http://www.floris.us/SO/form.php ):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && $_POST['EndTime']!='' && $_POST['Distance']!='') {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
        for ($StartTime = 1; $StartTime <= $_POST['EndTime']; $StartTime++) {
            echo"<tr><td>".$StartTime."</td><td>".$StartTime*$_POST['Distance']."</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    else {
        if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
            echo "You did not fill out all fields!";
        }
        echo '
            <form action="" method="POST">
                Total Trip Time: <input type="text" name="EndTime"><br>
                Miles Per Hour: <input type="text" name="Distance"><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>                 
            ';
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you for that but how would I do error correction for missing fields using this same method.

Comment: @Ruthless I have updated the code - now, if you fail the first condition, but the `$_POST['submitted']` was set, you know on of the other fields was not filled out - so you add error message. Obviously you can adapt from here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$_REQUEST` rather than use `$_POST`. If occur any error, post here and tell me what is the error.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submitted']) == "" || isset($_REQUEST['EndTime']=='') || isset($_REQUEST['Distance'] =='')) {
       echo '
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    Total Trip Time: <input type="text" name="EndTime"><br>
                    Miles Per Hour: <input type="text" name="Distance"><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>                 
                ';
        }
        else {
     echo "<table border='1'>";
            for ($StartTime = 1; $StartTime <= $_POST['EndTime']; $StartTime++) {
                echo"<tr><td>".$StartTime."</td><td>".$StartTime*$_POST['Distance']."</td></tr>";
            }

        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Validate using jquery or javascript

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) &&  isset($_POST['Distance']) && isset($_POST['EndTime']))
{
 echo "<table border='1'>";
        for ($StartTime = 1; $StartTime <= $_POST['EndTime']; $StartTime++) {
            echo"<tr><td>".$StartTime."</td><td>".$StartTime*$_POST['Distance']."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo '</table>';
}else{
    echo '
            <div id="err" style="color:red;"></div>
            <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">
                Total Trip Time: <input type="text" id="EndTime" name="EndTime"><br>
                Miles Per Hour: <input type="text" id="Distance" name="Distance"><br>
                                <input type="hidden" id="submitted" name="submitted" value="1">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>                 
          ';

}
?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    endtime = $("#EndTime").val();                   
    distance = $("#Distance").val();
    submitted = $("#submitted").val();
    if(endtime == "" || distance == "" || submitted == "")
    {
        $("#err").html("Please enter all fields");
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#err").html("");
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but we are not allowed to use javascript o html5 required.